# Is it possible to create new class properties dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this class with predefined `$student` property, it's working. What I want to do is create new properties dynamically using the values fetched in the database.

```php
class FormFirstApplication extends Component
{
    public $student;
   
    // New properties are added dynamically here on mount()


    public function createProperty($field, $val){
        $this->{$field} = $val;
    }

    // Execute on page load
    public function mount($old)
    {
        $this->student = $old;

        $s_fields = CustomField::where('field_section_id', 10)
            ->where('status', 'Active')
            ->where('student_type', 1)
            ->where('standard', 1)
            ->get();

        foreach ($s_fields as $standard) {
            $this->createProperty($standard->field_name, $standard->initial_value);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me this error... because that `photo` property not existing.

[image]

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that like this :-

```
class student(){
    public function mount($old)
    {    
        $s_fields = CustomField::where('field_section_id', 10)
            ->where('status', 'Active')
            ->where('student_type', 1)
            ->where('standard', 1)
            ->get();
            foreach($s_fields as $k => $field)
            {
                $this->{$k} = $field;
            }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: if it give you error , show it and show your code

Comment: the properties created successfully , this is another error in validation method .